Background color not being correctly applied to an element
I am learning css and I noticed that if I applied background color to all elements using the "*" attribute, although its being applied to the whole page and element ,the horizontal area next to the element is not showing background color. I have tried applying background color to element and body separately but still it doesn't get fixed. Any suggestions on how to fix this will be great help.


*{
    background-color: black;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Doc</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button>hi</button>
</body>
</html>




It sounds like the problem is just a space issue... If you don't have any other CSS for the page: try adding height: 100%; width: 100%; and/or margin 0; padding:0; and/or top:0; left:0; to your * {...} CSS style(s). All of which help to make sure that there isn't any irregular spacing when checking from one browser to another.

When using Bootstrap, some default styles may override your custom styles. You can use more specific CSS selectors or add !important to your styles.
for example:
You can use !important rule to give the 1st priority.


* {
    background-color: black !important;
}



or you can edit the background color for body tag.


body {
    background-color: black !important;
}



for your reference. here you can see the background color overrides by bootstrap css.


Thx a ton for help it solved the issue

It's because you're using bootsrap, it defines background color on body element:

You can increase specificity of body selector, for example add a class to body
<body class="your-body">
    <button>hi</button>
</body>

and then reference it by class in css:
.your-body {
  background-color: black;
}

UPD:
Using !important like this
body {
  background-color: black !important;
} 

or even this
* {
  background-color: black !important;
} 

could be also an option, but I would recommend to avoid it as it's not a good practice, especially when you just started learning.

Thx for taking time to help me solve this problem.
